# Disable console logging in JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, logging, console, jwplayer

JWPlayer outputs a lot of events in the browser console. How do I disable logging entirely?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a configuration option for JWPlayer.

Right-click on the player (Flash version here), then change the menu option "Logging to ..." until it's "Logging to none".

Answer (score 0):

While this question is quite old (2012), it is still the first Google result I found when looking for the answer.

Since I found out the answer myself I still want to post it here for other people looking for it:

In the JWPlayer config object there may be a part like this:

```
{
    playlist   : [...],
    title      : 'Some title',
    ... more options ...

    debug: {
        'levels' : 'all'
    },

    ... more options ...
}
```

Simply remove the debug-part completely and it will no longer output to the console (or at least not excessively).